# wp_remote_post and theme update problems using Azure App Service

Tags: wordpress, iis, azure

My business' Wordpress website has gone live in the last week, and I've been using Azure's App Service offering to run it. It's worked like a charm for the most part, but a couple of odd things have been plaguing its otherwise smooth operation, while making use of the [Avena](https://themeforest.net/item/avena-photography-wordpress-for-professionals/22617750) theme:

1. wp_remote_post
2. Theme updates

## wp_remote_post

I'm not a PHP developer, but from what I understand this is simply a function exposed to plugins, themes, and the like to allow for HTTP POST functionality. While my theme's diagnostics report that this doesn't work on either a local copy run on a temporary web server (macOS) or on Azure (IIS), a function which relies on this feature works locally, and not on Azure.

[image]

To give more detail, "rows" as you'd see them in your typical modern marketing website may have banded rows such that sections stand out more than others. I also have the option to add a "shape" to the edges of these rows, so that an otherwise straight line becomes the outline of a forest.

This pulls an `.svg` file from the local filesystem, and appears to use the `wp_remote_post` function to do it. However, I get the following error which demonstrates that this fails.

[image: wp_remote_post error message]

I would love to include the code snippet of what fails, but I'm not sure if my theme provider includes the right to do that in their licence.

## Theme updates

When I first downloaded the theme, it came with its own set of included plugins via `.zip` as they tend to. However, these would not install because Wordpress complained about the plugins being too old (or the theme being too old - can't remember now).

However, the relevant part of the issue is that attempting to update the plugins returned the error *Update Failed: Download failed. A valid URL was not provided.* In the end I needed to download the plugins myself through the Wordpress portal.

I didn't think much of that, but now that a theme update has been released, the update failed because of the same error.

[image: Wordpress theme update error]

## Summary

Apologies for this long-winded question, but I feel that the two issues are related, and I can't get help from the theme provider because they don't have experience with, or support for Azure App Services. I also can't get support from Microsoft for Azure because I don't have a paid support plan.